# Refused to load the script: https://apis.google.com/js/api.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement firebase authentication for a chrome extension. I can sign in using email and password, but I can't get the social logins to work (google and facebook)

here is the error message:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=__iframefcb541553' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "...",
  "description": "...",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "icons": {},
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "event.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "https://*/*","activeTab"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "...",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "css": [],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self';"
}
```

signin

```
  handleSocialLogin(provider) {
    return () => {
      auth
        .signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(user => {
          this.props.onUserChange(user)
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
        })
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error }))
    }
  }
```

Comment: Make sure you've reloaded the extension after editing manifest.json.

Comment: did you resolved your issue?